# Getting a "Request timed out" error after deploying to Heroku with node.js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, mongoose, async-await

The `/` route works fine and any other route that does not use `async/await` seems to work, but when I go to

```
router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  Post.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

It doesnt return any data and I get a "Request timed out error" in Heroku

I checked the `.env` file variables and tried using them on the `localhost:3000` and it works.

Here is the full routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');
const Post = require('../models/posts');
const path = require('path');

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Working');
}); //This route works

router.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  Post.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}); //This one gives me an error

module.exports = router;
```

The posts mongoose model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const postSch = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    required: true,
    type: String,
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
  },
  file: String,
});

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSch);

module.exports = Post;
```

The main `app.js` file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const mainRoute = require('./routes/mainRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const ejs = require('ejs');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index.ejs');
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secure: false,
    // maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * 7,
    // originalMaxAge
  })
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use('/', mainRoute);
require('./passportconfig')(passport);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

the `.env` file:

```
MONGO_URI="mongodb+srv://<account_name>:<password>@cluster0.f7aej.mongodb.net/web?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
COOKIE_SECRET="somerandomstring"
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs on the server side? You might have an error there.

Comment: Maybe your promise is being rejected and so nothing is sent to the frontend

Comment: I tried running the app on `localhost:3000` and Im not getting any errors, I also tried creating a fresh project and only connecting to a database and logging the results of `User.find({})` to the console. Im getting the same error. The app is working on the localhost and i can succesfully log the results of the `.find()` method but not on the heroku server.